# How do I copy a form across project spaces?

Tags: commcare

How do I copy a form from an application in one project space to a different application in another project space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy a form across project spaces by clicking the Actions tab (or Advanced tab if viewing app manager before the redesign) when viewing the Form and click Download. Once you have that file you can upload that same file to a different Form. Note that Case Management settings will not be copied.
[image]